# A question about solving directional derivatives

Tags: derivatives, quantile

The question comes from the paper ``Regression Quantiles'' by Roger Koenker and Gilbert Bassett(1978).

$0< \theta <1$. Define $\psi(b;\theta,y,X)=\sum^{T}_{t=1}[\theta-1/2+1/2 \; \text{sgn}(y_{t}-x_{t}b)][y_{t}-x_{t}b]$, where sgn(u) takes values $1,0,-1$ as $u \gtreqless 0$.

Here, $y_{t}$ is a scalar and $x_{t}$ is a $K \times 1$ vector.

Then \textbf{my question} is: what is the directional derivative of $\psi(b)$ in the direction $w$?

The paper states that the answer is 
\begin{equation}
\psi^{\prime}(b;w)=\sum^{T}_{t=1}[1/2-1/2 \; \text{sgn}^{\ast}(y_{t}-x_{t}b;-x_{t}w)-\theta]x_{t}w,
\end{equation}
 where 
 $\text{sgn}^{\ast}(u;z)= 
\begin{cases}
\text{sgn} \; u \; \text{if} \; u \neq 0,\\
\text{sgn} \; z \; \text{if} \; u = 0
\end{cases}$

But I do not know how to derive this result.

Comment: Is $b$ a vector (like $x_t$) as well? If yes, then $x_t b$ is the scalar product in $\mathbb R^K$, am I right?

Comment: Hi Avitus. You are right, it should have written as $x^{\prime}_{t}b$. But the original paper suppress the transpose.